# Setup Oracle database with docker-compose

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I want to start a Docker-container with Oracle XE and then run an SQL script (setup_database.sql) to create some tables in docker-compose.

How can I integrate the following commands into my docker-compose:

```
docker run -d -p 49161:1521 -v "$PWD":/duo --name duodb --hostname duodb --network duo-test -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true wnameless/oracle-xe-11g-r2
```

Run a terminal in container:

```
docker exec -ti duodb /bin/bash
```

go into the right directory:

```
cd duo/sql
```

Kick off the setup_database script:

```
sqlplus system/oracle@xe @setup_database
```

I've tried to do run this:

```
oracle:
    container_name: duodb
    image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g-r2 
    ports:
        - '49161:1521'
    volumes:
        - .:/duo
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sqlplus system/oracle@xe @setup_database"]
    environment:
        - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
```

But this outputs the following error:

```
Creating network "duo_default" with the default driver
Creating duodb
Creating duomail
Creating duolocal
Attaching to duomail, duodb, duolocal
duomail      | MailDev webapp running at http://0.0.0.0:80
duomail      | MailDev SMTP Server running at 0.0.0.0:25
duodb        | /bin/bash: sqlplus: command not found
duodb exited with code 127
duolocal     | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
duolocal     | [Fri Nov 15 08:17:55.944907 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: 172.20.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
duolocal     | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
duolocal     | [Fri Nov 15 08:17:55.977329 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: 172.20.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
duolocal     | [Fri Nov 15 08:17:55.980390 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.1.32 OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
duolocal     | [Fri Nov 15 08:17:55.980423 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Can you add the Container Log?

Comment: I've added the container log

Comment: can you share your solution please?

Answer (score 3):

I am not that docker expert, but as far as I know, the network is automatically created with all containers inside a docker-compose file, therefore you do not need the network. Furthermore, you can name the service so I think container-name is also not needed. In which version do you start the compose file? You could try something like this

```
version: "3"

services:
     duodb:
         image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g-r2 
         ports:
             - 49161:1521
         volumes:
             - .:/duo
         environment:
             ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
             MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
             MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
             MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database_name
```

Answer (score -2):

```
version: "3"

services:
  duodb:
    image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g-r2
    ports:
      - 49161:1521
    volumes:
      - .:/duo
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name
```